# Synchronous command doing the opposite of what identical asynchronous method does

Tags: c#, sqlite, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I built a very simple list-making app with Xamarin.Forms and the sqlite-net-pcl Nuget package. I have a single model, `ListItem`, with a boolean attribute `Active`. There are two lists: `activeItems`, where `Active = true`, and `inactiveItems`, where `Active = false`. When the user taps an item in the `activeItems` list, it is set to `Active = false`, and the two lists are reloaded. When the user taps an item in the `inactiveItems` list, it is set to `Active = true`, and the two lists are reloaded. All this works great.

However, I also want to give the option to permanently delete an item, not just mark it as complete. When a user long-holds an item's `MenuItem` (on either list) and selects "delete", the ListItem is deleted from the database as expected, but it isn't removed from the `activeItems` list, and the `inactiveItems` list vanishes completely (when I reload the page, the `inactiveItems` list is back and the `activeItems` list is missing the deleted item, as expected). This is really weird because I literally copy-and-pasted my "SetActive/Inactive" method into my "DeleteListItem" method. The only difference is that "DeleteListItem" is synchronous, but I don't see why that should make it do what it's doing.

Sidenote: for each method, I reload the `HeightRequest` of both lists, so they exactly fit their contents.

Anyone see the problem? Or if anyone knows how to make my "DeleteListItem" method asynchronous, that would be great too, on the off-chance that that's the issue.

**Update**

I tried making my "DeleteListItem" asynchronous, but the behavior didn't change. I also tried using `App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItemsAsync());` instead of `App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItems());`, because that's the method used in the methods that work. But then I get this error:

```
Error   CS1503
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<Myapp.Models.ListItem>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Myapp.Models.ListItem>'
```

---

**Xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="..."
             xmlns:x="..."
             x:Class="Myapp.ListPage"
             x:Name="ListPage">
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackLayout>

            <!-- CURRENT ITEMS LIST -->
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <ListView x:Name="activeList" VerticalOptions="Start" ItemTapped="SetInactive">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}">
                                <TextCell.ContextActions>
                                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListPage}, Path=DeleteListItem}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="delete" />
                                </TextCell.ContextActions>
                            </TextCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- PAST ITEMS LIST -->
        <ListView x:Name="inactiveList" VerticalOptions="Start" ItemTapped="SetActive" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}">
                    <TextCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListPage}, Path=DeleteListItem}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="delete" />
                    </TextCell.ContextActions>
                </TextCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code-behind: (uses methods defined in ListItemRepository.cs, defined as "App.ListItemRepo")**

```
using Myapp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using SQLite;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Myapp
{
    public partial class ListPage
    {
        public Command DeleteListItem { get; set; }

        public ListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> activeItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItems());
            activeList.ItemsSource = activeItems;
            activeList.HeightRequest = 50 * activeItems.Count;

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> inactiveItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItems());
            inactiveList.ItemsSource = inactiveItems;
            inactiveList.HeightRequest = 50 * inactiveItems.Count;

            });

            // DELETE METHOD
            DeleteListItem = new Command((parameter) => {
                ListItem item = (ListItem)parameter as ListItem;

                App.ListItemRepo.DeleteListItemAsync(item);

                ObservableCollection<ListItem> commandActiveItems =
                    new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                        App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItems());
                activeList.ItemsSource = commandActiveItems;
                activeList.HeightRequest = 50 * commandActiveItems.Count;

                ObservableCollection<ListItem> commandInactiveItems =
                    new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                        App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItems());
                inactiveList.ItemsSource = commandInactiveItems;
                inactiveList.HeightRequest = 50 * commandInactiveItems.Count;
            });
        }

        // SET AS ACTIVE METHOD
        public async void SetActive(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedListItem = e.Item as ListItem;
            await App.ListItemRepo.SetListItemActive(selectedListItem);

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> activeItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    await App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItemsAsync());
            activeList.ItemsSource = activeItems;
            activeList.HeightRequest = 50 * activeItems.Count;

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> inactiveItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    await App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItemsAsync());
            inactiveList.ItemsSource = inactiveItems;
            inactiveList.HeightRequest = 50 * inactiveItems.Count;
        }

        // SET AS INACTIVE METHOD
        public async void SetInactive(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedListItem = e.Item as ListItem;
            await App.ListItemRepo.SetListItemInactive(selectedListItem);

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> activeItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    await App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItemsAsync());
            activeList.ItemsSource = activeItems;
            activeList.HeightRequest = 50 * activeItems.Count;

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> inactiveItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    await App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItemsAsync());
            inactiveList.ItemsSource = inactiveItems;
            inactiveList.HeightRequest = 50 * inactiveItems.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

**Assets/ListItemRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Myapp.Models;
using SQLite;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Myapp
{
    public class ListItemRepository
    {
        private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection conn;
        private readonly SQLiteConnection syncconn;

        public ListItemRepository(string dbPath)
        {
            conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            conn.CreateTableAsync<ListItem>().Wait();
            syncconn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            syncconn.CreateTable<ListItem>();
        }


        public async Task SetListItemActive(ListItem listItem)
        {
            ListItem item = (ListItem)listItem as ListItem;
            var result = await conn.UpdateAsync(new ListItem { Id = item.Id, Active = true, Name = item.Name }).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        }
        public async Task SetListItemInactive(ListItem listItem)
        {
            ListItem item = (ListItem)listItem as ListItem;
            var result = await conn.UpdateAsync(new ListItem { Id = item.Id, Active = false, Name = item.Name }).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        }
        public async Task DeleteListItemAsync(ListItem listItem)
        {
            ListItem item = (ListItem)listItem as ListItem;
            var result = await conn.DeleteAsync(new ListItem { Id = item.Id }).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        }

        public Task<List<ListItem>> GetActiveListItemsAsync()
        {
            return conn.QueryAsync<ListItem>("select * from list_items where Active = 1");
        }
        public Task<List<ListItem>> GetInactiveListItemsAsync()
        {
            return conn.QueryAsync<ListItem>("select * from list_items where Active = 0");
        }

        public List<ListItem> GetActiveListItems()
        {
            return syncconn.Query<ListItem>("select * from list_items where Active = 1");
        }
        public List<ListItem> GetInactiveListItems()
        {
            return syncconn.Query<ListItem>("select * from list_items where Active = 0");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your command asynchronously. Just add async keyword before (parameter) in your DeleteListItem command. Then you should also call DeleteListItemAsync method asynchronously. Finally, call GetActiveListItemsAsync instead of GetActiveListItemsAsync.

```
        DeleteListItem = new Command(async (parameter) => {
            ListItem item = (ListItem)parameter as ListItem;

            await App.ListItemRepo.DeleteListItemAsync(item);

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> commandActiveItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    await App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItemsAsync());
            activeList.ItemsSource = commandActiveItems;
            activeList.HeightRequest = 50 * commandActiveItems.Count;

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> commandInactiveItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    await App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItemsAsync());
            inactiveList.ItemsSource = commandInactiveItems;
            inactiveList.HeightRequest = 50 * commandInactiveItems.Count;
        });
```

I hope it helps! If not, let me know :)

Comment: Thanks! But the behavior didn't change. This is so bizarre. I tried to change `App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItems` to `App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItemsAsync`, which is the method being used by the methods that work, but I get this error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<Myapp.Models.ListItem>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Myapp.Models.ListItem>'`. Do you know how I could remedy that?

Comment: are you awaiting that call?

Comment: Like Jason suggests, you should await call of this method.

Comment: Return type of async Task is different when called with or without await. @JoeMorano You should avoid calling async Task methods synchronously, trying to get .Result from them.

Comment: Huh, I swear I tried exactly that before but got some error. But now I put it back in and everything's working. I still have no idea why using a synchronous method would have caused the behavior I was getting, but at least it's fixed!

Comment: You should never rely on synchronous call of async methods ;)